# Android/Facebook - Why is the Facebook login page changing all the time?

Tags: android, facebook, image, authentication, screen

Since yesterday it seems that the Facebook login page I load in my Android applications that use the Facebook API are changing all the time. Sometimes I get this screen (which was the one I have always got):

[image: Facebook_Screen_1]

But now, sometimes, I get this screen:

[image: Facebook_Screen_2]

I have NO IDEA what is going on. I simply load the login screen using a WebView, as the code below:

```
    LinearLayout webViewContainer = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new FbDialog.FbWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
    mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    webViewContainer.setPadding(margin, margin, margin, margin);
    webViewContainer.addView(mWebView);

    mContent.addView(webViewContainer, new LayoutParams(400, 550));
```

Does anyone have any clue of what's going on?? Is anybody else experiencing the same issue since yesterday?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're probably A/B testing a new login screen.  Hence the mention of "alternative login".

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, its actually a link that is being directed via the User Agent. The page that is rendered is different between the two. Specifically the first one is the mobile website, whereas the other website is the desktop version. Try playing around with the User Agent and hard code it to use the mobile version.

Comment: Hi Jox. Thanks for replying. Once I didn't change absolute ANYTHING in the code, I assume that the User Agent, whatever it is, is the same. So, I assume that it's Facebook's fault. It's not something that surprises me much though. Facebook often change things as they please, without letting their users know about it...